# Creating a diagram of sentences connected by labeled arrows

Tags: arrows, linguistics

I am trying to create a diagram of sentences, with labeled arrows connecting sentences to each other, as well as individual words (see attached drawing). The idea of the diagram is presenting two kinds of linguistic prediction tasks, both based on a given input sentence (the central sentence in the drawing). For each task the model is presented with a modified version of the input sentence (the upper and lower sentences); in task 1 (upper part), it predicts a property of the entire sentence, while in task 2 (lower part), it predicts a property of each word in the sentence.

Is there a simple way to create such as diagram in latex?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us if there are certain rules behind this diagram. Is there something that fixes the number of `blah`, `blah2` and `blah3`?

Comment: Please add the information of your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can one draw such diagrams? Sure. However, there are many specialized packages that are particularly useful for a certain scenario. As long as you do not provide more details, you may miss the best choice(s). From what I see in your screen shot, I made a guess, and here is the result.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}[column sep=2pt]
blah2 \& blah2 \& blah2 \& blah2 \& blah2 \\[2cm]
blah \& blah \& blah \& blah \& blah \\[2cm]
blah3 \& blah3 \& blah3 \& blah3 \& blah3 \\
\end{deptext}
\begin{scope}[font=\sffamily]
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (\wordref{3}{\X}) --  ++ (0,-1.5) node[below]{\X};}
\path (\wordref{3}{1}) --  ++ (0,-1.5) node[midway,left=8mm] {analyze};
\path (\wordref{1}{1}) --  ++ (0,1.5) node[midway,left=8mm] {predict};
\draw[thick,-latex] (\wordref{2}{3}) --  (\wordref{3}{3})
node[midway,right]{task: analysis};
\draw[thick,-latex] (\wordref{2}{3}) --  (\wordref{1}{3})
node[midway,right]{task: prediction};
\foreach \X [count=\Z] in {subj,dobj,iobj}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (\wordref{1}{3}) --  ++ (-3+1.5*\Z,1.5) node[above]{\Z}
node[midway,left]{\X};}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\node[inner sep=0pt,fit=(\wordref{\X}{1}) (\wordref{\X}{5}),draw]{};}
\end{scope}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think that captures the main idea well. Is it possible to add borders around the sentences (I know how to add borders around nodes with "subjekt", but the text in this example is not within a node)?

Comment: @user1767774 Yes, it is. However, I will refrain from adding this as long as I do not know where the journey will go. After all, everybody having a similar question/problem should benefit from this answer. Please add some information to the question that allows other to understand what this is good for.

Comment: @user1767774 I added the borders using the `fit` library, and also want to warn you that `subjekt` will only work if you define a corresponding style, i.e it is AFAIK not something that comes with Ti*k*Z, one of its standard libraries, nor with the `tikz-dependency` package.